# Почему время редактирования комментариев ограничено до пяти минут?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено, editing

Это сделано для того, чтобы не получилось так, что кто-то прочитает чей-то комментарий, а тот его может почему-то решить совершенно изменить, и тогда первый не сможет вернуться к нему, если видит в нём что-то полезное для себя?

Если даже и так, то можно хотя бы ввести лимит максимального количества изменений, хотя бы до трёх знаков, для того чтобы ***можно*** было просто ***исправить ошибки и описки,*** которые иногда замечаешь через большое время, когда заглядываешь в вопрос со своим комментарием или комментариями.

Может, удастся это изменить и сделать, как я предлагаю или похоже на это? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ограничения на время редактирования существуют так как у комментариев нет истории правок. Более того, в модели вопросов и ответов они имеют второстепенное значение. Теоретически, в комментариях должны быть лишь уточняющие вопросы к автору сообщения, которые, после внесения изменений в сообщение, должны удаляться.